# JSDoc in VS code for documenting function with module's type

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I want to document a function written in another module, which uses http.ClientRequest typed parameter. I want something like this, but it does not work:

```js
/**
* @param {ClientRequest} req 
*/

function setToken(req) {
}
```

I have tried also `@param {http.ClientRequest}`, but it did not work.

*Update:* 
Basically I solved that problem by importing the required module by `import http from "http";`. However, I don't want to import it because this module does not use `http module` but provides helper functions.

Answer (score 7):

After improve answer from IGx89 I got a shorter variant without typedef. I prefer this variant when I reference to another module one time:

```
/**
* @param {import('http').ClientRequest} req 
*/
function setToken(req) {

}
```

But if you need reference to some type from another module with long path variant with typedef looks shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to the top of your file:

```
/** @typedef {import('http').ClientRequest} ClientRequest */
```

I had this same problem myself (though regarding a module in my own app) and also had a very hard time finding the solution. I eventually figured out the above syntax by reading through this issue in the TypeScript GitHub repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377

Comment: This is ideal...it makes sense to declare it at the top of the file. Thanks for a life-saver!

Answer (score -1):

It does not work because it is a custom type JSDoc don't know. You have to setup your own definition with a @typedef.

```
/**
* A number, or a string containing a number.
* @typedef {(number|string)} NumberLike
*/

/**
* Set the magic number.
* @param {NumberLike} x - The magic number.
*/
function setMagicNumber(x) {
}
```

See the full examples on [JSDoc typedef tag definition examples](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html#examples)

I made an example which worked for me with JSDoc 3.5.3

```
/** @typedef {ClientRequest} TestReq */

/**
* @param {TestReq} req 
*/
function setToken(req) {
}
```

[JSDoc output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow8nC.png)

Comment: In NodeJs there is a module named http. It has http.ClientRequest interface.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but the types depending on the javascript type definition (string, number, object, ...). So it is not possible that JSDoc know the type "http.ClientRequest". You need a custom type definition for it. Maybe you can workaround when you use @param {Object}, but this would make it really general.